# How to change the status bar color when scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm making an app for studies using the chucknorris api

I want that when the screen scrolls down, the status bar is transparent to match the text

[Before sliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvAIj.jpg)

[After sliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXHx4.jpg)

Comment: Look into `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. There are plenty of tutorials available online.

Comment: I didn't find any

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Add a listener to scrollview

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnScrollChangedListener(new 
            ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {

                    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        // bottom of scroll view, 
//you can change status bar color here

                    }
                    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                        // top of scroll view


                    }
                }
            });
```

Step 2:
change the status bar color inside scrollview listener with the following code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```